# Why are the lowest values of my output missing?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int i,j;
    long k;
    for(i=10;i<=99;i++)
    {
        for(j=10;j<=99;j++)
        {
            k=i*j;
            printf("%ld\t",k);
        }
    }
}
```

I am unable to get desired output.

It's not giving the lowest terms i.e. the terms less than 680. I have uploaded a small part of output screen.

[image]

Comment: "I am new in C programming" is not a good description of the problem. The title should summarize the issue, not your situation. Being a new developer is totally fine, but you need to explain yourself better.

Comment: Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are hostile to those who use screen readers. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. Use the `{}` button to format any blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect.

Comment: Why do you expect this to show values less than 680? HINT: You need an `if` statement

Comment: You need to keep a check until what value you loop or print.

Comment: Where is the 680 coming in? Where is the "less" coming in? Do not proide pictures of text. Learn how to format. Learn about the concept of StackOverflow ([tour]). Learn [ask]. Please. Otherwise, welcome to StackOverflow.

Comment: It wouldn't just be the problem that in your output the first lines have already left the scrollable area of your window? Try to redirect the output into a text file and open it with an editor. `myprog > output.txt`. Then you should see in the first lines values like "100 110 120 130".

Comment: Also you should write what the desired behavior is.

Comment: I have to apologise. This is one of the rare cases where showing a screenshot of your output actually carries relevant information - the scroll slider.

Comment: I ran your program and it printed values less than 680. Voting to close for not reproducible.

Comment: @klutt Run it in a small window buffer and it is reproducable.

Comment: Before close-voting, please read my answer and explain how the question could have been asked more clearly without knowing the answer. The code obviously should output values below 680 and they are not in the visible output, that is a good description of what the problem is. With the additional information given in the screenshot (yes picture is better than text here), the scroll slider, everything the asker had available is given. Please do not close vote unclear or too broad.

Comment: Aside: you have `long k` presumably to hold a result larger than `int` but (if `long` ***is*** larger than `int` on you system) you should cast one of the operands before multiplying: `k = (long)i * j;` because without that, the `int` multiplication is done and any overflow lost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first few lines, which probably look like

```
100 110 120 130 140 ...
```

are just not visible in your screenshot, because your window buffer is smaller than the total output. Therefor scrolling all the way to the top does not in fact show the first few lines.

In order to verify that, you could print line numbers, or the values of `i` and `j`.
Or you can redirect the output of your program into a textfile and open that with an editor.
The you will see all of the output of your program and I bet that you will find the values 100 to just below 680.

The fact that the lowest visible number is 680 and among higher values is explained by the two values in the product: 68*10==680; while the previous line ended in 67*99==6633. A few lines later you find 68*99==6732 and 69*10==690.

Comment: problem solved.

Comment: @AbhishekVerma if this was the best answer, please "accept" it by checking the box.